# Why does open.window() stops fast css-animation in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, animation

Can anyone explain me this strange css-animation thing in Firefox (41)? If the animation is very fast (e.g. 1s) it stops when opening a window using javascript by onclick. But it does not happen when using the direct link with the href attribute. If the animation is long enough, e.g. 4s the animation play correct if a new tab is openend by javascript. Do anyone know a how to fix this?

```
<head><style>
.movingBox{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    animation: animateThis 1s 0s ease-out 1 forwards;
}
.link{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
@keyframes animateThis{
    from {left:0px;}
    to {left:1000px;}
}
</style></head>

<body><div class="movingBox"></div>
<a  class="link" onclick="window.open('www.example.com','_blank')"></a></body>
```